# Strange behavior of the jQuery horizontal scroll script

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my page structure:

```
<div id="page1">
  <div id="page1-1">
    <a id="firstPage"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="page1-2">
    <a id="secondPage"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="page1-3">
   <a id="thirdPage"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="page1-4">
    <a id="fourthPage"></a>
  </div>   
</div>
```

on every page there is a basic menu like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="#firstpage">First page</a></li>
 <li><a href="#secondPage">Second page</a></li>
 <li><a href="#thirdPage">Third page</a></li>
 <li><a href="#fourthPage">Fourth page</a></li>
</ul>
```

and it's my jQuery script:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#page1 ul.menu li a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = jQuery(this);
        jQuery('#page1').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: jQuery($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And here starts the "fun" part. It scrolls fine if I click on anchor: from 1st to 2nd page, from 1st to 3rd, from 1st to 4th. When I am on 2nd, it won't scroll to the third one, but scrolls to 4th. If I am on 3rd, it won't scroll to 4th and when I click on 2nd , it scrolls to the first. If I am on 4th, it always scrolls to the first one except when I click on the 4th - then it scrolls to the second.

I know it is a little bit confusing, but what I noticed is that it won't scroll to the one on the right except when You are on 1st page, and it always scrolls to the first when you are on any other page except when you are on 4th and click on 4th (then it scrolls to the 2nd).

I am trying to figure it out second day and would appreciate the help so much.

I am doing this on Joomla platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is on `jQuery('#page1').animate()`, you should animate body. The following seems to work fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#page1 ul.menu li a').bind('click',function(event){
        var scrollTo = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().left;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: scrollTo
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
#page1 { 
  display: flex;
  width: 400vw;
}

div > div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page1">
  <div id="page1-1">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#firstPage">First page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#secondPage">Second page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#thirdPage">Third page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fourthPage">Fourth page</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a id="firstPage"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="page1-2">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#firstPage">First page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#secondPage">Second page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#thirdPage">Third page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fourthPage">Fourth page</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a id="secondPage"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="page1-3">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#firstPage">First page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#secondPage">Second page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#thirdPage">Third page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fourthPage">Fourth page</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a id="thirdPage"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="page1-4">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#firstPage">First page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#secondPage">Second page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#thirdPage">Third page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fourthPage">Fourth page</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a id="fourthPage"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice notice, but my page contains more vertical slides and one of them has a horizontal scroll. If I target body then it tries to scroll all the window and it doesn't work. Thanks for answer , looking forward for more advices maybe?